# JavaScript prototype overriding

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am new at learning JavaScript concepts. Want to understand how prototypical inheritance work. My impression was if your class inherits its parent, and you have a same named method in prototypes of both classes, when you call the method on child instance, the method in the child prototype will be called.

Code:

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.printName = function () {
    console.log(this.name + ' in animal prototype');
}

function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
}



Cat.prototype.printName = function () {
    console.log(this.name + ' in cat prototype');
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

var anm1 = new Animal('mr cupcake');
anm1.printName();


var cat1 = new Cat('cat');
cat1.printName();
```

On calling cat1.printName() I expected it to log 'cat in cat prototype' but it logged 'cat in Animal prototype'. Could someone please explain the reason to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct, but your override of the `printName()` function is, itself, being overridden by the next line when you reset the `Cat.prototype`. Simply moving the order of the code fixes the issue:

```js
function Animal(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.printName = function() {
  console.log(this.name + ' in animal prototype');
}

function Cat(name) {
   Animal.call(this, name);
}

// OLD LOCATION of code

// This was overriding your override!
// Setting the prototype of an object to another object
// is the basis for JavaScript's prototypical inhertiance
// This line replaces the existing prototype object (which is
// where your override was) with a completely new object.
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

// NEW LOCATION
// AFTER setting the prototype (and creating inheritance),
// it is safe to do the override:
Cat.prototype.printName = function() {
  console.log(this.name + ' in cat prototype');
}

var anm1 = new Animal('mr cupcake');
anm1.printName();  // "mr cupcake in animal prototype" 

var cat1 = new Cat('cat');
cat1.printName();   // "cat in cat prototype"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.